# Minecraft keeps crashing without mods or packs in PE edition

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I go on to a world, my own saved or one on my LAN server, it starts to load then crashes. Minecraft PE doesn’t even detect the crash. I don’t use anything but the default resource and behaviour packs. What is causing the crash and how can I fix this?

This Post is Answered, So don't attempt to answer

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem before. If the device you are using is an old model (5+ years old) Minecraft PE will not work well. Also make sure Minecraft is fully updated, the software on your device is also updated, and that you have a decent amount of available storage space on your device.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated everything (I don’t look at my emails often, so that is why I made a late response) and it seems to be just the specific world now. I deleted that world and now it is working fine